# Flash animation of a clock that counts to 24:00 (24hours) lineair within timeframe?

Tags: flash, time, counter, clock

I'm making an animation that's based a period of time. I'm making a timeline of 3600 frames and I need counter that counts to 00:00 to 24:00 (with periods of 00:05 each -> 00:05, 00:10.. .. 00:55, 01:00, 01:05)

And it should measure how fast (or when to go to next 00:05) within the 3600 frames.

Is there any possibility of making that with code, or should I change the clock every few frames with +00:05).

I hope someone could provide me some code or advice.

Thanks!

Comment: What I think there should to come: A piece of code that ads 00:05 to a clock element (which is pure text, or if you know something better), every 6 frames. 

Thanks!

Comment: The advice would be to not use 3600 frames (not use multiple frames) for the timing, instead use a Timer that fires every 5 seconds. Also, use a Date object to get the actual time, in the code you trigger every 5 seconds using the Timer, and derive time passed from that, rather than adding 5 seconds each time, since neither Timer nor frame events are timed exactly enough to give correct timing values over 24 hours. In other words - get a start value from a Date object - every 5 seconds (approximately), get a new time value from a Date object and compare the two to determine actual time passed.